# How Do I Enable Filter Functions in CA Agile Central?

Tags: javascript, rally

I need to employ a filter function to implement a heuristic for selecting records.  Simple field/value checks, alone, are inadequate for our purpose.

I'm trying to follow the examples for function filters, but for some reason, the "allowFunctions" flag keeps getting set to false.

I attempt to set the **allowFunctions** property to true in the storeConfig:

```
            storeConfig: {
                models: ['userstory', 'defect'], 
                allowFunctions: true,                   
                filters: [{
                    // This did not work ...
                    property: 'Iteration.Name',
                    value: 'Sprint 3',
                    // Trying dynamic Filter Function.  Update: Never called.
                    filterFn: function (item) {
                        console.log("Entered Filter Function!");
                        var iter = item.get("Iteration");
                        console.log("Iteration field: ", iter);
                        if (iter !== null && iter !== undefined) {
                            return (iter.name === "Sprint 3");
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
```

After the grid view renders, I inspect it the store configuration and its filters:

```
            listeners: {
                afterrender: {
                    fn: function (_myVar, eOpts) {
                        console.log("Arg to afterrender: ", _myVar, " and ", eOpts);
                        var _myStore = _myVar.getStore();
                        console.log("Store filters: ", _myStore.filters);
                    }
                }
            },
```

What I find is that the allowFunctions property has been set back to false and I see that the filter function I specified never fired.

[Console Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d3SC.png)

So either I am setting allowFunctions to true in the wrong place, or something built into the Rally Grid View and its data store prohibits filter functions and flips the flag back to false.

OR there's a third option betraying how badly off my theory of operation is.

Oh, wise veterans, please advise.

Here's the entire Apps.js file:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function () {
        //Write app code here
        console.log("Overall App Launch function entered");
        //API Docs: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/
    }
});

Rally.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define('BOA.AdoptedWork.MultiArtifactGrid', {
        extend: 'Rally.app.App',
        componentCls: 'app',

        launch: function () {
            console.log("onReady Launch function entered");
            this.theGrid = {
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                showPagingToolbar: true,
                showRowActionsColumn: false,
                editable: false,
                columnCfgs: [
                    'FormattedID',
                    'Name',
                    'ScheduleState',
                    'Iteration',
                    'Release',
                    'PlanEstimate',
                    'TaskEstimateTotal',
                    'TaskActualTotal', // For some reason this does not display ?? :o( ??
                    'TaskRemainingTotal'
                ],
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: {
                        fn: function (_myVar, eOpts) {
                            console.log("Arg to afterrender: ", _myVar, " and ", eOpts);
                            var _myStore = _myVar.getStore();
                            console.log("Store filters: ", _myStore.filters);
                        }
                    }
                },
                storeConfig: {
                    models: ['userstory', 'defect'], 
                    allowFunctions: true,                   
                    filters: [{
                        // This did not work ...
                        property: 'Iteration.Name',
                        value: 'Sprint 3',
                        // Trying dynamic Filter Function.  Update: Never called.
                        filterFn: function (item) {
                            console.log("Entered Filter Function!");
                            var iter = item.get("Iteration");
                            console.log("Iteration field: ", iter);
                            if (iter !== null && iter !== undefined) {
                                return (iter.name === "Sprint 3");
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                context: this.getContext(),
                scope: this
            };
            this.add(this.theGrid);
            console.log("The Grid Object: ", this.theGrid);
        }
    });


    Rally.launchApp('BOA.AdoptedWork.MultiArtifactGrid', {
        name: 'Multi-type Grid'
    });
});
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one since you still want your server filter to apply and then you want to further filter the data down on the client side.

Check out this example here:
https://github.com/RallyCommunity/CustomChart/blob/master/Settings.js#L98

I think you can basically add a load listener to your store and then within that handler you can do a filterBy to further filter your results on the client side.

```
listeners: {
    load: function(store) {
        store.filterBy(function(record) {
            //return true to include record in store data
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with allowFunctions, but in general remoteFilter: true/false is what controls whether the filtering is occurring server side or client side.  remoteFilter: true + the load handler above gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Kyle, man, thank you so much.

Yeah, the reason for wanting to keep the simple value screens is to narrow the result set against which the function is applied.  I'm afraid of horrible performance if I just try to do all filtering in the function on the client side.

There is probably 15 years of data in this Rally instance.  I know the project context will knock that down a lot, of course, but still, even projects have a lot of history.  So, date ranges and simple value criteria needs to make the result set as small as possible.